# Changes reflecting in payload but is not getting applied on target widget in workdetails page in casemanager 5.2.1

Tags: dojo, payload, ibm-content-navigator, ibm-case-manager

In Workdetails page, under ‘Documents’ tab, when I set the alignment to ‘center’ from ‘right’ for the column value, its getting updated in payload but is not actually getting applied on target widget. 
I have tried thru controller/Grid as well but its not getting set. Attached snap of same. A pointer in this regard would be of immense help.

Here is the snip:

```
var callbackFolderContent = function (resultset) 
{
var classText = 'Abc';
var found = 0;
for (var i=0; i < resultset.length; i++)
{
    var items = resultset[i].resultSet.items;
     for (var j=0; j < items.length; j++)
     {
        var pos = id.indexOf(classText);                                                              
        if(pos !== -1)
        {
            var PC= items[j].resultSet.structure.cells[0][3];
            if(PC.styles=="text-align:right;")
            {
            PC.styles="text-align:center;";
            var NEWpc=PC.styles; //Its reflecting in payload.
            alert("Changed aligning to: "+NEWpc);
            }
            found ++;
            } //end f if loop
      } //end of inner for loop
} //end of for loop
if (found < 1)
    {
    payload.stateCode = 4;
    payload.hideMessage=true;
    abort({silent:true});
    } 
    else
        {
    complete();
      }
    }; //end of callback function
```